# iosart2c table* will make next table caption overflow into second column

Tags: tables, two-column

In the two-column layout of iosart2c, the very next "table" after a "table*" will have its caption incorrectly flow into the second column, thus overlapping with the text there. Is this a known limitation or a bug? How can I correctly confine the caption?

**Minimal Working Example for the table caption overflow bug.**

```
\documentclass{iosart2c}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\caption{This table will make the next one overflow.}
\end{table*}

\begin{table}
\caption{This caption should be broken into a single column but won't as it runs into the second column.}
\end{table}

Some text to show that we indeed have two column layout and that it overlaps.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this with some standard class as well? If not, please provide a link to that documentclass-file! If you consider this to be a bug, you should report it to the maintainer of that class. It would be off-topic in this case.

Comment: The above example works fine when using \documentclass[twocolumn]{article} so it could really be a bug. I found the document class file online at https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/kwarc/doc/macros/ext/iosart/iosart2c.tex.

Comment: Probably a good idea in this case to update to iosart2x: https://github.com/vtex-soft/texsupport.iospress-isp/blob/master/iosart2x.cls

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the class does a questionable definition of `\@maketablecaption`; fixing it and fixing also `table` and `table*`, the result is what's expected.

```
\documentclass{iosart2c}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@maketablecaption#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\footnotesize #2}%
  \centering
  {\footnotesize#1\par}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa>\tablewidth
    \parbox[t]{\tablewidth}{%
      \footnotesize%
      #2\vphantom{Ay}\par
    }%
  \else
    \mbox{\box\@tempboxa\vphantom{Ay}}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip
  \endgroup
}
\renewenvironment{table}
  {\let\@makecaption\@maketablecaption
   \tablewidth=\columnwidth
   \let\@floatboxreset\@tableboxreset\@float{table}}
  {\end@float}
\renewenvironment{table*}
  {\let\@makecaption\@maketablecaption%
   \tablewidth=\textwidth
   \let\@floatboxreset\@tableboxreset\@dblfloat{table}}
  {\end@dblfloat}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table*}
\caption{This table will make the next one overflow.}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}
\caption{This table will make the next one overflow. This table will make the next one overflow.
  This table will make the next one overflow.}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{table}
\caption{This caption should be broken into a single column but won't as it runs into the second column.}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick fix. Use `\hbox` inside the caption. `\hbox` make the text to span across the table width --- addresses the later issue. Use multiple `\hbox` in chain to manually split the legend --- solution for former issue.

```
\begin{table*}[!t]
\caption{\hbox{The table shows the number of words in the master file --- selected based on} \hbox{along with their letter count}\label{xyz} }
.
.
```